# How to setTheme to an activity at runtime? It doesn't work call setTheme before onCreate and setContentView

Tags: android, themes

I want `setTheme` to an activity at runtime, I have search some solutions by google.
someone said call `setTheme` before onCreate and setContentView can works, the code section like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    setContentView(...)
}
```

but it not works, I want to know, is there another solution can setTheme to activity?

Comment: Just try this - set your theme after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and before `setContentView(...)`

Comment: @hermanbrain : Always call `super.onCreate(...)` first in your `onCreate(...)` method unless you're intending to modify the `Bundle` you pass to it. As SpK says, call `setTheme(...)` after you call `super.onCreate(...)`.

Comment: Same problem, i even tried placing it as praveen said but no success. I made a custom theme in style.xml and added the line setTheme(R.style.MyCustomTheme); do i need to do anything else?

Answer (score 23):

Just try this - set your theme after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and before `setContentView(...)`

Like below code -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar); // Set here
    setContentView(...)
}
```

Comment: i tried this , but it shows the black background , can  you help me.

Comment: @mdDroid Dis you find the solution for the black background

Answer (score 10):

Actually this only worked for me if I set it before calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final int themeRes = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_THEME_ID, 0);
    if (themeRes != 0) setTheme(themeRes);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //ect...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
setContentView(...);
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
setContentView(...);
```

It must work well..

More on Themes, Read this
http://entertheinfinity.blogspot.in/2016/06/designing-android-interface-themes.html

Comment: I use this technique to change the theme on the Starting Activity of the app. It is because in the onCreate there is no View(i.e no action bar loaded or any view in activity) in which the theme can be set. 
Setting the theme before setContentView()  is like Setting a theme to null View.

My Analogy. It's always on you to decide.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To set the theme at runtime and fix the "black background" problem:

1. the theme should be set before `onCreate()`.

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ...
       setContentView(...)
   }
   ```
2. the theme of the transparent activity in the android manifest should be set to any theme that has a transparent background (e.g. a dialog theme).

   - this tells the Android OS continue to draw the activities behind the transparent activity so that you don't end up with a black background.
   - i'm using an `AppCompatActivity`; i need to use an `AppCompat` theme:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.example.app">
         ...
         <application
             ...>
             ...
             <activity
                 android:name=".TranslucentActivity"
                 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog"
                 .../>
             ...
         </application>
     </manifest>
     ```

Comment: Thanks, setting the theme in AndroidManifest works when your third module sets the theme dynamically and the `app` module uses `Material Theme`.