# How do I change the Activity's theme using styles.xml at runtime

Tags: android, android-activity, android-xml, android-theme

There are 3 different types of style in the `styles.xml` like the following:

```
<style name="Theme_A" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#01AC50</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark>#FF007838</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#009688</item>"
<style>
```

The users are able to choose which style they want using the buttons, **how can I change the whole Activity's style after clicking on the button**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to setTheme to an activity at runtime? It doesn't work call setTheme before onCreate and setContentView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134943/how-to-settheme-to-an-activity-at-runtime-it-doesnt-work-call-settheme-before#11238505) has the suggestion to use

> ```
> setContentView(...);
> setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
> setContentView(...);
> ```

That is: it seems you need to `setContentView` after `setTheme`, [as](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTheme(int))

> [`setTheme`] should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

You need to use `setTheme()` Function  before the `setContentView()`

as doc say's you need to define Theme before the view instantiate.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);
     .
     .
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```